# Apply R function to multiple objects and rewrite object

Tags: r

I'm trying to do the following:

- define a function which creates an additional column based on existing columns in a data frame
- apply said function to multiple objects (data frames), rewriting the original data frame

For example, say the function is to divide the Petal.Length by Petal.Width in iris.

```
divvy <- function(mydataframe){mydataframe$divvy <- mydataframe$Petal.Length/mydataframe$Petal.Width}
```

This part is easy.

Now imagine I have three (or three thousand) iris dataframes:

```
iris2 <- iris
iris4 <- iris
iris5 <- iris
```

What I am trying to avoid is this:

```
iris <- divvy(iris)
iris2 <- divvy(iris2)
iris4 <- divvy(iris4)
iris5 <- divvy(iris5)
```

times infinity for the number of iris data frames that I have

... with something along the lines of

```
lapply(c(iris,iris2,iris4,iris4), function(x) divvy(x))
```

And end up with iris, iris2, iris4, and iris5 having the new divvy column. How do I do this?

*Please note*: I do NOT want to create a meta-object that has all of the irises within it.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `data.table` to do this:

`library(data.table)`

```
 divvy <- function(x){x[,divvy := Petal.Length/Petal.Width]}

iris2 <- data.table(iris)
iris4 <- data.table(iris)
iris5 <- data.table(iris)

test <- lapply(list(iris2,iris4,iris5), function(x) divvy(x))
```

Where test looks like this (just showing the first 2 elements of the list):

```
> test
[[1]]
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species    divvy
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 6.500000
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 7.500000
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
 ---                                                                     
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 2.260870
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 2.631579
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 2.600000
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 2.347826
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 2.833333

[[2]]
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species    divvy
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 6.500000
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 7.500000
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 7.000000
 ---                                                                     
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 2.260870
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 2.631579
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 2.600000
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 2.347826
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 2.833333
```

EDIT***  In response to OP updating questions specs:

You could try this:

```
for(i in c("iris2", "iris4", "iris5")){
  x <- divvy(get(i))
  assign(paste0(i,"divvied"), x)
}
```

Although i'd recommend against `assign`, especially for a lot of objects. You could extract the elements from the `test` list which i made in the first half of the answer, you'd still get the same answer, just a little cleaner and less clutter.

What the code does is pulls in the `iris` data tables as a string, and then reads them using `get`. This is passed to your divvy function, creating a data.table `x`. I then use assign to create the data.table with the suffix `divvied`.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure how to clarify my question to make this clear: the problem isn't defining the function, which is what your data table implementation solves nicely. The problem I'm *actually* asking about/trying to solve is about not having to generate the new test object which has the list of iris data frames in it - I want to modify the irises in place.

Comment: Clarified the wording in the question to try to make this clearer

Comment: Does this mean that you want to create "infinity" objects in your environment?

Comment: It means that, yes, I already have infinity objects in my environment, I just want to batch modify them. Realistically, I'm usually doing this on 12 - 20 objects, so not actually infinity - but I want to be able to write one line of code to define the function, and one line of code to apply it across all of the datasets.